# Getting a mac address from a device via web script or http

Tags: javascript, php, python, perl, http

Is it possible, considering I have access to all of the end user devices to allow security exceptions, to request the device mac address using any web scripting process running in Apache/IIS/Nginx? PHP? Perl? ASP?

Client devices are running iOS so this won't work http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=19&title=MAC-Address-Using-WMI-on-Internet-Explorer

It must be possible because MDM solutions get it through a Config Profile...

Answer (score 0):

In a word: no.

Actually, using the standard protocols/technologies you mentioned above it is not possible to retrieve the MAC address of the client.

What is possible is using a legacy technique where you install a "native" software on the client machine (e.g. activeX, java applet...).
That software, once installed, can retrieve easily the MAC of the client's device. Thus, it could call your web server with the MAC as an argument.

Nothing of the scenario above is expected to be implemented or is already implemented.